# How we call sync Webservice in iOS9

Tags: objective-c, ios9

How we call sync call But the give response asynch.here is my code.

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com"];
 NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

 NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
 NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                         completionHandler:
     ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
         // ...
     }];

 [task resume];
```

Answer (score 0):

We can't and we never could.

The previous approach was halting the execution of the tread, continuing after getting the data or after a timeout.